# Error when using the WebView control in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, wpf-controls, windows-store-apps

I'm developing an App for the Windows Store using WPF. I almost done, but recently I'm getting an error when trying to use the WebView control to display some internet content.

I use a second page for this. So in the loaded event of the page I have:

```
void Page2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.MyWebView.Source = new Uri("http://www.google.com.mx");
}
```

When running the App and after clicking in the button that navigates to Page2, the above method is executed. However, I'm getting the ***Just-In-Time debugger window*** saying:

> *An unhandled exception ('Object doesn't support property or method 'isHomePage'') occurred in MyAppName.exe [6736]*

But, despite this error the specified url is loaded and displayed.

Does any one know why the *Just-In-Time debugger window* appears? And how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are debugging your WebView-enhanced application, and the webpage hosted inside the WebView has a JavaScript exeception, it will throw up a horrible Debugger dialog like this one:

[image]

It's not really a helpful dialog in the context of your C#/XAML application. You can get rid of this annoying box by disabling Script Debugging in Visual Studio:

Debug > Options and Settings > Debugging > Just-In-Time > Uncheck "Script":

[image]

You will no longer be bothered by that again.

From [Windows Store Developer Solutions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN10)

Comment: Excellent answer and link. However, the only question I have is: is it only happening when debugging, rigth? I mean, it won't appear when the user download the App?

Comment: Yes, it's only in debug mode, not in release mode.